# Initilized django form field value not being saved in database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to create a form that creates a new model instance like below. But, although the instance is created, the fields are empty even though I initilized the form fields using the init method.

Here is my forms.py

```
class ChatForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user_id = kwargs.pop('user_id')
        super(ChatForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        user = User.objects.get(id=self.user_id)
        self.fields['user'].initial = user
        self.fields['var1'].initial = "new string data"

    class Meta:
        model = NewModel
        fields = (
            'var1',
            'user',
        )
```

Here is my views.py. I am using django forms for backend validation only.

```
def view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_id = request.POST.get('user_id')
        
        form = ChatForm(request.POST, user_id=user_id)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return JsonResponse({'status': 'success'})
        else:
            errors = form.errors.as_json()
            return JsonResponse({'status': 'error', 'errors': errors})
    return HttpResponse('Not a valid request method')
```

My models.py is simple. var1 is a charfield and user is a foreignkey field to a User model. The problem is that the instance is created, but var1 and user is blank for some reason. I hope you can help me with this, and leave any comments below.

Comment: Move the `super` to the end line of `__init__` method